# My audio file is not playing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysqli, jplayer

I have a jplayer here to play an audio: [AUDIO](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/previewaudio.php?filename=Kalimba.mp3)

Problem is that it is not playing my audio file I have. How can I get the audio to play?

The audio files comes from the directory `AudioFiles/Kalimba.mp3`. I retrieve the directory from the db and then tell the jsplayer to play the audio in this directory. This should have then played the audio but nothing happens if I click on the play button

jplayer summary here: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/step-8-audio/

Below is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Preview Audio</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="jquery/skin/jplayer.blue.monday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$getaudio = 'AudioFiles/' . $_GET['filename'];

$audioquery = "SELECT AudioFile FROM Audio WHERE (AudioFile = ?)";

        if (!$audiostmt = $mysqli->prepare($audioquery)) {
        // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}


// Bind parameter for statement
$audiostmt->bind_param("s", $getaudio);

// Execute the statement
$audiostmt->execute();

            if ($audiostmt->errno) 
            {
                // Handle query error here
            }

$audiostmt->bind_result($dbAudioFile); 

$audiostmt->fetch(); 

$audiostmt->close(); 

?>

    <script type="text/javascript">   
        $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp4: "<?php echo $dbAudioFile; ?>"
          });
        },
        swfPath: "/jquery",
        supplied: "mp3"
      });
    }); 
    </script>  
<?php echo "File Path " . $dbAudioFile; ?>
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
  <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
      <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
        <ul class="jp-controls">
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jp-progress">
          <div class="jp-seek-bar">
            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
          <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-time-holder">
          <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
          <div class="jp-duration"></div>
          <ul class="jp-toggles">
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Please stop cheating with multiple accounts and asking the same question multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14305295/285587)

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean. There maybe other people asking similar questions as a lot of us are doing similar work but I have one account only

Comment: Btw that link you posted, you can't display what you have displayed as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debug it with console, ex. firebug (ff plugin) and paste the result here please

Comment: I will do this give me 5 mins, but can you put this as a comment rather than an answer as it isn't an answer. Btw which result do you want to see, the html, the console? Which tab should I go on in firebug

Comment: first tab - console. it will display all javascript errors on page

Comment: Sorry, just had my dinner. I will do this now

Comment: IT was a destination of swf path that needed to be changed. I have no errors now in firebug but still not playing the audio I have

Comment: I accidentally put mp4 when its mp3